# Creation module through package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I very badly understood how I can develop my new modules.

In node_modules\npm\node_modules I create folder **myx** with 2 files
**package.json**

```
{ 
"name" : "some", 
"main" : "lib.js" 
}
```

**lib.js**

```
console.log('lib');
```

I run server

```
require('myx');
```

Error:
Cannot find module 'myx'

Comment: npm is for shared modules, you likely want to just create a new file `myx.js` populate it with code and then in another file do `require('./myx.js')`;

Answer (score 2):

You should never manually edit anything inside a node_modules folder.  That folder is managed by the npm package manager, and it may overwrite your changes.

If you just want to `require` a file, just put the file in your app's folder and use a qualified filesystem path like `require('./myx')`.

If you want to create a new *module* which you will use in multiple projects and/or publish to the public npm registry:

1. Create a new folder for your module – for example *myx*.
2. Run `npm init` in that folder.  It will help you create a package.json file.
3. Create your js files.

You can now `require` your module from other projects by using a fully-qualified path.  For example,

```
require('/home/me/myx');
```

Node uses its [file loading rules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) to determine exactly which js file from your myx folder will be loaded.

Loading the module this way is fine for development and testing, but you probably want to install the module into your projects (just like other modules).

Fortunately, npm supports [installing from sources other than the registry](https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html).  In your project folder, run:

```
npm install /home/me/myx
```

npm will install the module into your project's node_modules, which means you can just

```
require('myx');
```